# Restrict adding controls to ToolStrip

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer, toolstrip

I am designing a series of `ToolStrip` controls for specific jobs eg Font ToolStrip. What I need to do is stop user and developers from adding or removing controls from my ToolStrips.

Any help will be gratefully accepted
Danny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create such custom `ToolStrip` you should perform this steps:

1. Create a class and inherit from `ToolStrip`.
2. Disable default designer of `ToolStrip`.
3. Hide `Items` property in property grid.

Here is detailed  descriptions about steps:

- **Create a class and inherit from `ToolStrip`.**

  This way you can add some items to your custom toolstrip at designer. To do so, after creating your class open it in design mode (it may take some times to visual studio detect it can open the file in designer). Then go to properties window and using `Items` property add some items. You can also select items from dropdown above properties window and in events tab, handle `Click` event and add some logic.

  **Note:** After adding items, go to code view and call `InitializeComponent();` is constructor.
- **Disable default designer of `ToolStrip`**

  You should disable default designer of `ToolStrip` to prevent changing items at design-time, so users can not use designer versb or design surface to change items. To do so, it's enough to decorate your custom component class with `[Designer(typeof(ControlDesigner))]` attribute.

  ```
  [Designer(typeof(ControlDesigner))]
  public class MyToolStrip : ToolStrip
  {
      //...
  }
  ```
- **Hide `Items` property in property grid.**

  You should hide `items` property aslo in property grid to prevent changing items through property grid. To do so, it's enough to override `Items` property and decorate it with `[Browsable(false)]`.

  ```
  [Browsable(false)]
  public override ToolStripItemCollection Items
  {
      get
      {
          return base.Items;
      }
  }
  ```